# Application crashes on lollipop when `preDexLibraries` is true

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, unity-game-engine, android-multidex

I have added an `aar` file in my project. The size of aar file is around `50 MB`, Its a unity game that runs inside the app. The size of `apk` of my current app is around 82 MB, so with this `Unity library`, it takes apk size to `130 MB`

By default i was using these dex options.

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
    preDexLibraries false
}
```

Now when `preDexLibraries` is set to false, the gradle operation fails with following error message.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
```

and if i set `preDexLibraries` to `true`, it builds and runs successfully on lollipop+ devices, but fails on lollipop with the following error message.

```
11-21 17:43:25.229 14213-14213/com.myapp.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.myapp.app, PID: 14213
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.myapp.app.AnalyticsSampleApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.myapp.app.AnalyticsSampleApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.app-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp.app-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:628)
   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4966)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:177)
   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1493)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5912)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

where as `AnalyticsSampleApp` is the my Application class, that extends from `Application`

I googled this, but still unable to understand what`preDexLibraries` actually does.

> **preDexLibraries** (the answer of your third Q): it builds dex file out of libraries so it can be used in incremental builds (not building
>   dex files every time for libraries). so using this item when clean
>   build makes everything a little slower.

Comment: Since you extend Application, you have to override the `attachBaseContext` function then call `super.attachBaseContext(base);` inside it followed by `MultiDex.install(this);`

Comment: @Programmer : I am targeting lollipop+ devices, do i still need to do this? I have just enabled multidex from gradle

Answer (score 1):

Please add  multiDexEnabled true inside the  defaultConfig {...} inside the gradle.

eg:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.savingyou.android'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
       }
```

and add compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' inside dependencies{.....}

eg:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':aars')
    compile 'com.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
}
```

If it doesn't workout,please create a class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;

    public class EnableMultiDex extends MultiDexApplication {
        private static EnableMultiDex enableMultiDex;
        public static Context context;

        public EnableMultiDex(){
            enableMultiDex=this;
        }

        public static EnableMultiDex getEnableMultiDexApp() {
            return enableMultiDex;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            context = getApplicationContext();

        }
    }
```

and in your manifest give android:name="packagename.EnableMultiDex"

eg:

```
<application
    android:name="YourPakageName.EnableMultiDex"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/wowio_launch_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    tools:node="replace">
```

Comment: Thanks, but after adding this the crash is still there.

Comment: Yes same error log, this is only happening in lollipop devices